# org-fill-paragraph leaves a comma at end of C style comment

Tags: org-mode, comment, fill-paragraph

In a src block when there is a C style comment /* ... */ doing an org-fill-paragraph would always put a comma just before the last star, like this:

```
/*
Some comment
,*/
```

Is there a way to stop it from doing so?

Comment: This is because `*` has special meaning in org. Comma here escapes the asterisk. When you export this document, the comma should be removed.

Comment: You could use `C-c '` to edit in appropriate major mode and use it to refill your comments inside of src blocks.

Comment: I insert small snippets while writing code documents, it would be a hassle dropping down with C-' every time.