# org src block php formatting adding commas to phpDoc

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

In the editing mode (C-c ') I formatted php code using TAB button. But in org mode src block it adds 2 comma to phpDoc.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to with your TABs.

org src blocks put a comma before every * that starts a line (that is the first non-space character).
I think it's just a way to not confuse other org-mode commands.

Comment: I found similar topic [org-fill-paragraph-leaves-a-comma-at-end-of-c-style-comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36381/org-fill-paragraph-leaves-a-comma-at-end-of-c-style-comment) and even someone already submit it as a issue [spacemacs issue](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/10286). It looks horrible how I can remove it. I think org-mode should be disable in src code block. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really need to remove it to your org file? If you want to export your file, org-mode will remove it for you. But if it is just to look nice, you can replace all `",*"` with `"*"`. Your org-src block should evaluate normally, but I can't guarantee that some other org commands won't conflit with that.

Comment: I see this inconvenient syntax as a way to preserve previous org functions that use `*` as a special character.